# hide pagination before printing - primeng table

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component **Bill** with a print button

`<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="printBill()"> Print </button>`

and a child component **BillProducts** has p-table

`<p-table [value]="products" [loading]="loading" [paginator]="allowPaginator" [rows]="1">`

I want to hide the paginator and display all products when the client clicks on print button

```
printBill() {
    this.allowPaginator = false;
    window.print();
  }
```

but what is happening is hide paginator after printing the document not before that.

any suggestions?

Comment: If print is a part of primeng table then you can't it. You should write custom print for this. or you need to close pagination for that table

Answer (score 1):

You can try to delay a little bit `window.print()`. It's running before angular change detection takes place to update the view. Try this:

```js
printBill() {
  this.allowPaginator = false;
  setTimeout(() => window.print(), 300);
}
```

I have a feeling that you don't even need the `300ms` value: just put the `window.print()` at the start of the queue in the event loop to be handled after the current loop is finished:

```js
printBill() {
  this.allowPaginator = false;
  setTimeout(() => window.print());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by the following :

```
printBill() {
    this.allowPaginator = false;
    setTimeout(() => window.print(), 1000);
  }

  @HostListener('window:afterprint')
  doAfterPrint() {
    this.allowPaginator = true;
  }
```

Thanks.